# How well does COVID vaccination protect against brain damage from COVID?

Tags: vaccination, coronavirus, brain-damage, omicron

I have read that even mild infections with the Corona virus causes significant brain damage in a large number of cases: [Could mild COVID symptoms lead to brain damage?](https://www.deseret.com/coronavirus/2022/1/21/22894780/mild-covid-19-symptoms-brain-damage-side-effects)

Therefore, it is natural to ask whether vaccination protects against brain damage. Suppose one had received three vaccine doses of Pfizer; how well would one be protected against brain damage arising from an infection with the Omicron variant?

Here is an article written before the onset of Omicron: [Another Reason to Get a COVID-19 Vaccine: Avoiding Brain Damage](https://www.usnews.com/news/health-news/articles/2021-11-04/avoid-brain-damage-with-a-covid-vaccine-and-booster)

Comment: Welcome to the site. Unfortunately it is a bit too early in the Omicron wave to be answering this question - it would require some serious data collection and crunching. So, while it might be being looked at, I don't think the answer is known yet. The data may be available for Delta or another strain.

Comment: I have to agree with @bob1. I don't think this question will be answerable for months.

Comment: Isn't it remarkable then that we allow a majority of our population to become infected, risking a very significant drop in intelligence in the general populace?

Comment: @AlgebraicsAnonymous It's a big jump from some mouse studies and 48 highly motivated subjects with undisclosed comorbidities reporting "brain fog" on a preprint server to "a very significant drop in intelligence in the general population". Also, no one is "allow[ing]" our population to become infected. Public health authorities do not have complete control over the population, as can be seen in the US.

Comment: @IanCampbell Of course, a competent government would instantly instate lockdowns. Furthermore, we are talking about much more than mice studies. A quick startpage.com search will turn up several studies concerning other variants, which show that across variants, there is quite a significant IQ. drop.